# Angular 2, @Input or OnInit lifecycle hook and hitting server?

Tags: angularjs, performance, input, server

I am wondering which solution is better. I have url like : http://localhost:3000/product/3. I have two options to pass Product model to component:

1. Using @Input and pass product (from another component) without hitting the server
2. Implement OnInit lifecycle hook and always hitting the server when user invoke this url.

Of course better performance is in first solution but I am not sure if this is proper solution. Any recomendations or another issue which can appear in first solution ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very depend on which data you are trying to pull from server. Let's talk about two cases:

1. If server will host millions of products there is absolutely no reason to get all that products before user will ask for special one. So in this case, `onInit` request will be more reasonable.
2. But in case you know that server always fixed small amount of products, let's say - 50 products. I would say in this case you can take them on the init of application and be sure, that user will not have to wait each time he is jumping between products.

In production reality case #1 is more common, because you never know how many products will be pushed by content managers. But take decision according to your business rules.

Comment: But what if I manually changed url from ../product/3 to ../product/4 ? In case of @Input it wont work am I correct ?

Comment: @user3528733, It will, you just need to choose best mechanism to implement it. You can put all products to service for instance, and depend on url parameter - `products/5`,  get specific product from service. Or you could put to Input specific item from service depend on parameter in url